# Display is wrong resolution, aspect ratio, and size

Tags: nvidia, xorg, display, display-resolution, xrandr

So last night (April 13th), I installed an update from Canonical that popped up in a GUI, it said something about a security update (I didn't look at it too hard).  Since then I've rebooted my machine and now the display is the wrong resolution (it ought to be 3840 x 2160, 597mm x 336mm, 60fps [monitor](https://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-27UD58-B-4k-uhd-led-monitor)).  I'm presently on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

```
$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00*
```

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GM107GL [Quadro K2200] driver: N/A 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: fbdev,nouveau 
  unloaded: modesetting,vesa resolution: 1024x768~76Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.0 256 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 20.2.6
```

I've tried unplugging and replugging the monitor, rebooting several times, adding an xrandr modeline, and changing `/etc/default/grub` to have `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.alpha_support=1"` (where it was `"quiet splash"` before).  None of these have led to any success.

My feeling is that there's some graphics driver issue (that the renderer is `llvmpipe` doesn't seem right).

I guess there's also a confounding factor in that I'm running the display through a [KVM switch](https://www.tripplite.com/2-port-displayport-usb-kvm-switch-4k-60-hz-hdr%7EB005DPUA4), but I really hope that's not the problem.  I've been using it for a while anyway with no issue, the Windows 10 partition of this machine renders fine, and  I have another machine running 18.04 that gets the resolution just fine.

Update:

I tried booting into recovery mode, which was no dice (also tried cleaning up `dpkg` through the recovery interface).  While I was in the GRUB menu, I noticed that it defaults to the kernel version 5.8.0-49, but that I also had 5.8.0-48 installed.  Booted into the older kernel, and everything works.  Curious, I checked the logs.

```
$ cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep linux-image
2021-04-13 23:15:01 install linux-image-5.8.0-49-generic:amd64 <none> 5.8.0-49.55~20.04.1
```

And that lines up with when I did that update.  So it seems that a kernel update messed up display detection somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a temporary solution but I recommend you try booting Ubuntu in safe mode and see if it helps

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  This didn't end up being the solution, but put me on the path to finding a different kernel in the GRUB menu.

Comment: Did the different kernel help?

Comment: yeah it did.  I'll submit an issue to canonical, not sure if something's configured weird on my machine or they messed up